# Image is not repeating when finish once

Tags: android, image, animation

I want to show the number of images with fade in fade out animation it's working fine but the images are not repeating when complete once. 
I want to show in the loop, I am not getting what is missing Any one have an idea about it?

My code is looks like below

**MainActivity.java**

```
animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_fade_in);
        animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_fade_out);

        Animation.AnimationListener animListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                changeImage(animation);
            }
        };

        // Set listener to animation
        animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(animListener);
        animationFadeOut.setAnimationListener(animListener);

        // Start fade-in animation
        imgBanner.setImageResource(R.mipmap.banner1);
        imgBanner.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);


public void changeImage(Animation animation) {
        if (animation == animationFadeIn) {

            // Start fade-out animation
            imgBanner.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);

        } else if (animation == animationFadeOut) {

            count++;

            // Set next image after fading out previous image
            switch (count) {
                case 1:
                    imgBanner.setImageResource(R.mipmap.banner2);
                    imgBanner.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    imgBanner.setImageResource(R.mipmap.banner3);
                    imgBanner.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    imgBanner.setImageResource(R.mipmap.banner4);
                    imgBanner.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    imgBanner.setImageResource(R.mipmap.banner5);
                    imgBanner.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**anim_fade_in.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

**anim_fade_out.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <alpha
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.1" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want the `changeImage` function's switch case to loop once you have reached the count = 4. You can simply place `count = count % 4` just before the switch case. This way your count will always remain within 0-3 and you can cycle through the images correctly. You will also need to change the switch cases. The code becomes this :

```
else if (animation == animationFadeOut) {

        count++;
        count = count % 4; // Enable recycling the count variable

        // Set next image after fading out previous image
        switch (count) {
            case 0: // Change cases such that count values form 0-3 are addressed
                imgBanner.setImageResource(R.mipmap.banner2);
                imgBanner.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                break;
            case 1:
                imgBanner.setImageResource(R.mipmap.banner3);
                imgBanner.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                break;
            case 2:
                imgBanner.setImageResource(R.mipmap.banner4);
                imgBanner.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                break;
            case 3:
                imgBanner.setImageResource(R.mipmap.banner5);
                imgBanner.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Currently your count becomes 5 at one point and the switch case ignores it, thus not running another animation.